# EJB and persistence exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb

By working with **Java EE**, I defined a *persistence layer* that exposes serval **DAOs** (extending `GenericDAO` and by using **Hibernate** as *ORM*).

Then, I inject a certail DAO in order to work with it into another class.

```
@Inject
private MyDAO myDAO;

public void writeSomething(String key, String data) {
    try {
        myDAO.create(key, data);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        // BLOCK 1
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // BLOCK 2
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to test exceptions, by trying to write an entry duplication.
As expected, the application returns an error, but it isn't a `ConstraintViolationException` instance, but something else (in fact, `EJBException`).

```
11:42:19,065 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-3) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component MyDAO for method public java.lang.Object my.app.dal.genericdao.GenericDAOImpl.create(java.lang.Object) throws java.lang.IllegalStateException,javax.persistence.PersistenceException,org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry
```

How can I to catch a specific exception thrown by `myDAO` according to the situation (in this case a constraint violation)?

Answer (score 6):

You can catch the `EJBException` and unwrap it using `exception.getCause();` to decide on further strategy.

However, I would not let the DAO throw `PersistenceException` into the application, wrapped or not. It will pollute your code with duplicate boilerplates with error handling on a different abstraction level.

It is advisable to handle the immediate failure inside the DAO and, if no recovery is possible, throw a business-centric application exception.

For cases, where a constraint violation is possible because you are trying to store a duplicate, consider querying for duplicates first and then modify and store the query result if appropriate. Relying on catching `Exceptions` instead is less readable and less efficient.